# WinPython: "NameError: name 'time' is not defined", but only inside a function

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm using WinPython to run my Python program using a USB flash drive.
But when I try to run an imported function inside a function I created, I receive the following error (it happens with any imported module):

> NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Here is an example that works fine:

```
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Here is an example that doesn't work:

```
import time
def waitLoad():
    time.sleep(0.2)
waitLoad()
```

I receive the following error executing the example above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\scripts\ptpython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "E:\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\ptpython\entry_points\run_ptpython.py", line 55, in run
    six.exec_(compile(open(a['<arg>'][0], "rb").read(), a['<arg>'][0], 'exec'))
  File "../testeMouse.py", line 4, in <module>
    waitLoad()
  File "../testeMouse.py", line 3, in waitLoad
    time.sleep(0.2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

If I execute the same program using the Python interpreter installed in my computer, the program works fine. But I need to execute it using the Python interpreter installed in my USB flash drive.

Comment: that is another *time* ? 0.2 vs. 0.5 in  testeMouse.py ?

Comment: no.
Any function inside a "def" gives me the same error.
For example, if i change time.sleep() for pyautogui.locateOnScreen(), the error will be:
"NameError: name 'pyautogui' is not defined"

Comment: Your traceback is generated from different code than what you posted. can you post the real code?

Comment: I've not encountered winpython so deleted my last comment but a quick search suggests it's used for spyder. I'm assuming you have `time` floating around in the namespace as something other than the module. Is there a kernel to restart?

Comment: Matthew Story, sorry, I copied from the wrong test file. Now the traceback is from the correct code.

Comment: @roganjosh i'm not using spider. I'm executing the code directly from the interpreter. Maybe that's the problem. I will try executing it using spyder then i will come back to confirm if it worked.
Probably you're right!

Comment: It's possible that something like that is going on but I've realised I don't know enough about exactly what you're doing so I don't want to send you on a tangent, sorry. An ipython oddity might explain a 1-off but if you're claiming that it's with any imported module then there's possibly some scoping I don't understand.

Comment: @roganjosh yep, the problem was really it. Executing the program using spider made it work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by executing the program using spyder.exe (an IDE included in WinPython). It wasn't working before because I was trying to execute the program directly by the Python interpreter installed on my USB flash drive.