# wont register or allow me to import time module in python

Tags: python, time, module

I am trying to import the time module into my python code and it does not recognize time as a module. I am using Visual studio code.

I can use other modules such as random and that works fine. I've tried importing just the sleep command and that doesn't work either
ex.)

```
from time import sleep

print ('hi)
time.sleep(1)
print ('hello')
```

but this unfortunately did not work as well. when I run the previous it returns the following:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Jacob/Repositories/python/testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

the code below is what I'd like to use In my code and still does not work and gives the same error. To clarify I am trying to use the time module and python is not recognizing it as a module when using both the previous and following code.

```py
#this is just an example for what I need for my program.
import time

print ('hi')
time.sleep(1)
print ('hello')
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton ive tried both those and neither work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126979/winpython-nameerror-name-time-is-not-defined-only-inside-a-function

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry for the unclear results, I've summed up my problem as best I can.

Comment: @bart thanks for the recommendation to a question but I've looked at this and our problems are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question.

`time` is one of the modules in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) (search for `time` in that list of modules). That is why you cannot `pip install` it. You may be using a distribution of Python does not not have the full standard library, but that is unlikely.

Probably something has gone wrong with your Python installation. That does happen--it has happened to me. Try re-installing Python on your system then try again. If you have trouble with the re-installation, read the directions of your distribution and try again. If you still have trouble, ask your computer supervisor if you have one. If not, you could ask a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with the import you probably need to install the time package

once you have it, this should work:

```py
from time import sleep

print ('hi')
sleep(1)
print ('hello')
```

Comment: this makes sense do you know how or where i would download the time package. I've tried using pip install time in command prompt but it did not recognize it.

Comment: "from time import time" line allowed me to make start = time() work. Thanks for the tip...